# How to Create a Design-Time Component Using Skia Canvas in Delphi Athens?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, skia4delphi

I'm working on a custom component in Delphi Athens that utilizes the Skia Canvas for rendering. I've managed to get the component functioning correctly at runtime, but I'm encountering issues when trying to make it work at design time (AccessViolation). I'm wondering if I need to initialize something specifically for design time, such as setting ALGlobalUseSkia to true, but I'm unsure where and how to do this appropriately in a design-time context.

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How are we supposed to reconstruct your issue? We also would "_greatly appreciate any insights or examples_" from you.

Comment: Built in Skia components work properly. So your question lacks [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure that is even possible. Since design-time components are rendered by Delphi IDE the IDE itself would have to be compiled with `ALGlobalUseSkia ` set to true. Even if we only talk about FMX components. While at runtime FMX components are rendered using DirectX or OpenGL at design-time  they are all rendered using GDI+. That is why some FMX components look differently at design-time compared of how they look at runtime.